# Extract city boundary from TIGER data

Tags: postgis, tiger

I'm trying to find the bounding box of US cities but I just can't seem to figure out what to do with the TIGER data I download (not to mention, which data to download!). Could someone experienced with TIGER data (or shapefile) help me with this?

How do I read/extract TIGER data to grab bounding box of cities? Trying to find lat/lon points that bound the city. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
Sorry for the ambiguous question. Basically, what I want to extract are coordinates of each bounding box for ALL US cities. For example:
New York (12.123,34.345),(12.456,34.678),..etc
Boston (11.111,22.222),(11.123,22.234),..etc
...etc (for all cities in the US)

I'm asking for this because I have a lot of coordinates that needs to be categorized (or reverse-geocoded) into cities, like (A,B) -> City A; (C,D) -> City B; etc. I can't use Google's geocoding feature because they only allow up to 5000ish requests per day per IP address, and I have millions of coordinates. I've tried installing OpenStreetMap data and running reverse-geocoding on my machine, but was turned off by the inaccuracy of results. Hopefully this made sense!

Comment: Do you need to use TIGER data? Geocoding with Google will return bounding boxes of cities.

Comment: What GIS software and version are you using to do this? You can use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with these details.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have PostGIS that I ran with OpenStreetMap data. I have no idea how to use that for TIGER or if TIGER uses that GIS software.